# Python: Execute Exception code only if not caught

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Say I want to make an Exception always trigger some code, like writing a file or calling an external program, but only if it is not caught. How can I do this?

A non-working example:

```py
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        with open('foo.txt', 'a') as stream:
            stream.write("Something bad happened.\n")

try:
    raise MyError()
except:
    print("Just kidding.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a `try/except` block that surrounds the entire script.

```
try:
    main()
except MyError:
    with open('foo.txt', 'a') as stream:
        stream.write("Something bad happened\n")
```

If anything in `main()` catches the exception, it won't be caught here, so nothing will be logged.

Comment: My goal was to `import` the exception in other programs and always have it do the specified action if not caught, which is why I wanted the code to live in the exception class itself. I do realize that this is not the usual task of an exception, but I thought it might still be possible.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I don't think the exception object is involved in the catching process.